# Сводка сэмплов android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eсть куски музыки, они воспроизводятся при нажатии кнопок. Каким образом сделать запись воспроизводящихся звуков, чтобы можно было сохранить сводку сэмплов? Пишу под android.
Нашёл только класс, который записывает голосовые звонки или с микрофона.

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сколько я знаю для подобных вещей есть класс **MediaRecorder**

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html

Answer (score 2):

Не проще ли было бы в сводку сохранять цифры( ID сэмплов ), а уже потом их где-нибудь склеивать в соответствии с залогированной последовательностью цифр?